# Liouville's theorem for non constant functions

Tags: entire-functions

I have to show by using Liouville's theorem, whether there are non-constant entire functions such that:

$$  |f^k(z)| \leq 1 \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$ and fixed $k$.

1. for $k=0$: There is such a function.
2. for $k\geq1$: There shouldn't be such a function, because $f(z)$ is not necessarily bounded, isn't it?

Comment: Did you mean $f^{(k)}$ instead of $f^k$?

Comment: Yes, $f^{(k)}$.Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f^{k}$ stands for the $k-$ th power then $|f^{k}(z)| \leq 1$ is same as $|f(z)| \leq 1$ provided $k \neq 0$. Hence $f$ is a constant if $k \neq 0$. If $f^{k}$ stands for the $k-$ th derivative then any polynomial of degree at most  $k$ with leading coefficient small enough ; the answer is $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{k} c_j z^{j}$ with $|c_k| \leq \frac 1 {k!}$.

Comment: Sorry. It stands for the k-th derivative. I have to specify all Funktions. How can I do that?

Comment: @SvenMath I  have written the complete answer now.

Comment: Thank you:) Why is $|c_k| \leq \frac{1}{k!}$

Comment: When you calculate the k-th derivative you will get just one term, namely $k! c_k$; this must be bounded in absolute value by $1$.

Comment: I see:)  Can i ask you another example. Is there a entire non-constant function, where $ f( \mathbb{C})$ is in the upper half plane?

Comment: @SvenMath Picards theorem says if $f$ is a non-constant entire function then  the range is either $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb C \setminus \{a\}$ for some complex number $a$.

Comment: We didnt have that. I have to argue with Liovilles theorem?

Comment: @SvenMath $e^{if(z)}$ is a bounded entire function, hence constant. From this it follows that $f$ is also a constant.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. How do get to $e^{if(z)}$

Comment: Can you answer this, please?

Comment: @SvenMath $|e^{if(z)}|=e^{ Re\, if(z)}=e^{- Im \, f(z)}<1$. It is not a good idea to ask new questions in comments. Please post a  new question.

Comment: Thank you for all your help:) I will do that:)